# Two states cpu-less PWM generation

Tags: pwm

I need to design a circuit that outputs a 5V PWM with a frequency of 50Hz and a duty cycle between (5% and 10%). If you are familiar with R/C servos this's the typical signal to drive servo position. This circuit should output the PWM with 5% duty cycle until an event (another 5V TTL signal) change state from low to high. Once the event have been caught the PWM signal should change to 10% duty cycle. The accuracy in duty cycle should be better than 0,1%.
It's not mandatory that the circuit reset to initials conditions after the input signal goes back to low (but it's welcome).
My first approach was to use a small micro but unluckly this's not the case since I cannot use programmable devices in this application.
I was thinking to use NE555 or NE556 IC but as far as I remember duty cycles below 50% and very low frequencies as those I need to manage are not very stable.

Comment: Use a CMOS 50Hz Relaxation Osc and a CMOS voltage controlled one shot solution scaled to give 5to10%

Comment: Would you consider using a microcontroller?  Look at the PIC10F family from Microchip.

Comment: @AlmostDone "My first approach was to use a small micro but unluckly this's not the case since I cannot use programmable devices in this application." Not in this case as it seems.

Comment: @AlmostDone as I wrote I cannot use microcontrollers.

Comment: You said a 555 is not stable enough. Please edit your question and add what stability/accuracy you require.

Comment: Engineers don't take kindly to arbitrary restrictions, "I can't use resistors, I'm not telling why".

Comment: If the problem is stability at low duty cycles, consider using two 555s; one as a 50Hz oscillator, the other as a 1ms/2ms monostable triggered by the first.

Comment: @pipe it's mainly a matter of money needed to certify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LTC6992](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQkIvAp4rbAhXmIcAKHeuxAzIQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftechnical-documentation%2Fdata-sheets%2F69921234fc.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3d0V8Y7T-YdZcXYzvo38M_) is a pulse width modulation chip: -

[image]

The above picture shows it operating at 1 MHz. Here are some more top-level details that can be found in the data sheet: -

> Minimum Duty Cycle at 0% or 5%
>
> Maximum Duty Cycle at 95% or 100%
>
> Frequency Range: **3.81Hz** to **1MHz**
>
> 2.25V to **5.5V** Single Supply Operation

The only thing you have to do is set the input voltage you want that corresponds with 10% duty cycle.

Your only constraint was that you can't use a micro: -

> My first approach was to use a small micro but unluckly this's not the
>   case since I cannot use programmable devices in this application.

So this fits the bill given precisely what you have indicated. Note that goal post moving is not generally well-received.

Comment: "Note that goal post moving is not generally well-received." sorry but I'm not that good in english... what do you mean?

Comment: @weirdgyn He means that new restrictions often comes up in this type of questions after a valid answer has been posted, such as "Oh, I can only use components from my local store" etc., invalidating old answers. So far you have not done that, so you're in the clear!

Comment: ahhh yeah... xcuse my ignorance !

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to output either pulses of 1ms or 2ms in a 20ms grid. Your 0,1% accuracy calls for a crystal oscillator.

Use a 1MHz crystal, divide the clock by 1000 using a cascade of three CD4017 counters. You have a 1ms clock now. Use another CD4017 for the "1ms, zero" and "1ms, one" outputs you need and a single toggle flip-flop for discriminating the first 10ms from the second.

Feed these three inputs and your 1ms/2ms select into combinatorial logic. You are done.